# Flash/Actionscript, Hidden Characters

Tags: flash, actionscript, ide

I wanted to try something out in Flash. I must have pressed some key combination by accident but now it is showing me all these extra characters in my AS code.

It shows the characters ">>>" for all the indents in the code, a "P" for all the line-breaks in the code, and a dot every time I press the spacebar.

If someone could help me get rid of this so my eyes don't fall out of my head I will owe you my vision.
It obviously doesn't mess up the while compiling but I can't look at my code with all this crap everywhere, who would even want this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You turned on Hidden Characters.

To toggle them on and off, click `View` > `Hidden Characters`.

**Hotkeys:**

Windows: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `8`

Mac: `Command` + `Shift` + `8`

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I didn't know how to Google search that because it wasn't a programming question. It actually was Ctrl + Shift + 8.. But I never would have gotten that if you didn't lead me to the right place. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Jay Whoops! Sorry about the `B`/`8` typo! Glad you got it sorted!